# SSRS Expression count query

Tags: reporting-services

I have table where want to display a count of all cases opened in last 30, 90, 180 and 12 months.

I have following expressions which errors when I run my report. I specified the team name and count is on Involvement ID.

Any ideas.

This is my expression:

```
=CountDistinct(iif(Fields!Team.Value="AAC",(IIF(DateDiff("d", Fields!OPEN_DATE.Value, Now) <= 30,Fields!INVOLVEMENT_ID.Value,Nothing))))
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox37.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `IIf` function doesn't have a third argument:

```
=CountDistinct(iif(Fields!Team.Value="AAC",(
IIF(DateDiff("d", Fields!OPEN_DATE.Value, Now) <= 30, Fields!INVOLVEMENT_ID.Value, Nothing)
), ...))
```

Comment: Ok I have had a look but I am struggling to get this to work.

Comment: Have you tried providing the required arguments for your function? If so, please post an updated expression and explain what problem you're experiencing.